# Compare two dataframes for changes in variable value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I'm trying to compare two dataframes with the exact same amount of rows and variables, for changes in variable value per unique ID (returning True if the value is the same, and false if it is different).  Here's an example of how the data looks:

df1

```
id col1 col2
1  abc  123
2  def  456
3  ghi  789
```

df2

```
col1 id col2
ghe  3  789
abc  1  123
def  2  455
```

And I guess I would have the result of the comparison be in df3

```
id col1 col2
1  true true
2  true false
3  false true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Hopefully I've made this somewhat clear.

Comment: Do you mean to have the 3rd row of `df2` have `id` 2?

Comment: Are all `id`s from `df1` present in `df2`? Exactly once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cbind.data.frame(id=df1$id, df1[-1]==df2[match(df1$id, df2$id), names(df1)[-1]])

#  id  col1  col2
#1  1  TRUE  TRUE
#2  2  TRUE FALSE
#3  3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Save a couple of keystrokes - `cbind(df1["id"], df1[-1]==df2[match(df1$id, df2$id), names(df1)[-1]])`

Comment: `cbind` will change the logical values. That's why `cbind.data.frame`

Comment: that's why I changed the first df1 selection to use the square brackets so that it was still a data.frame. That means it will get passed to the cbind.data.frame method.